# Finding last value and second to last value In Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataset and would like to see that last and second to last person to hold the same position.

Sample Data

```
  ID    Date        Name      Job        Job_ID  
  101   01/2022     Adam      Sales       1234
  101   02/2022     Adam      Sales       1234 
  101   03/2022     Adam      Sales       1234
  102   01/2022     Blake     Tech        2345
  102   02/2022     Blake     Tech        2345
  102   02/2022     Blake     Consultant  3456
  103   01/2022     Chris     Advisor     4567
  103   02/2022     Chris     Analyst     5678
  103   03/2022     Chris     Analyst     5678
  104   01/2022     Debbie    Consultant  3456
  104   02/2022     Debbie    Consultant  3456
  104   03/2022     Debbie    Tech        2345
  105   01/2022     Eric      Analyst     5678
  105   02/2022     Eric      Advisor     4567
  105   03/2022     Eric      Advisor     4567
```

Desired Output:

```
ID     Name     Job          JobID        Lastest   Prior  
101    Adam     Sales        1234         Adam      Adam 
102    Blake    Consultant   3456         Blake     Debbie
103    Chris    Analyst      5678         Chris     Eric 
104    Debbie   Tech         2345         Debbie    Blake 
105    Eric     Advisor      4567         Eric      Chris
```

I have code to get the last:

```
 manager_dict = df.groupby('ID').agg({'Name':'last'}).to_dict()['Name']
 df['Latest'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda x: manager_dict[x])
```

I just don't know how to get the second to last person to hold that position.

Comment: So, am I correct that you want a row for each `ID`, with the row being the same as the most recent row in the `Sample Data` with that `ID`, with two columns concatenated on: `Latest` (which will be identical to `Name`) and `Prior` (which is the `Name` of the previous person to have that `JobID`, if there is a previous person, otherwise its the `Name` of the same person)?

Comment: @Joe That is correct

Comment: How do you know that Blake is the last Consultant? Both Blake and Debbie have that job in 02/2022.

Comment: Or should `02/2022     Blake     Consultant` in fact be `03/2022     Blake     Consultant`?

Comment: @Nick it's clear that Debbie had that position before Blake by looking at her earliest date in the position.  It wouldn't surprise me for 2 people to have the same job in a month, one for the first part and one for the last part.  Certainly you'd expect robust code to handle the possibility.

Comment: @MarkRansom agreed on all your points, but it's also not clear that they didn't both (at the same time) have the job in 02/2022, and given that Blake doesn't have an entry for 03/2022, maybe they got fired. Hence my request for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
out = (
 df.sort_values(by='Date', key=pd.to_datetime)
   .assign(Latest=lambda d: d['Name'], # optional
           Prior=lambda d: d.groupby('Job_ID')['Name']
                            .transform(lambda x: (u:=x.unique())[len(u)-2]))
   .loc[lambda d: ~d.duplicated(subset='Job_ID', keep='last')]
   .sort_index()
)
```

Output:

```
     ID     Date    Name         Job  Job_ID  Latest   Prior
2   101  03/2022    Adam       Sales    1234    Adam    Adam
8   103  03/2022   Chris     Analyst    5678   Chris    Eric
10  104  02/2022  Debbie  Consultant    3456   Blake  Debbie
11  104  03/2022  Debbie        Tech    2345  Debbie   Blake
14  105  03/2022    Eric     Advisor    4567    Eric   Chris
```

Comment: You do have a slight inconsistency in your data caused by the inconsistency in OPs data (for index `10` you have `Name == 'Debbie` but `Latest == 'Blake`). See my comment to the question; I manually edited `df.loc[5, 'Date'] = '03/2022'` to make things work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do this, by first grouping by `Job_ID` and then aggregating `Name` 2 more ways to generate `Latest` and `Prior`, then joining that back to the original groupby:

```py
def prior_unique(g):
    u = g.unique()
    return u[-2] if len(u) > 1 else u[-1]

gg = df.sort_values('Date', key=pd.to_datetime).drop('Date', axis=1).groupby('Job_ID')
last = gg['Name'].agg(Latest='last', Prior=prior_unique)
out = gg.agg('last').join(last).reset_index().sort_values('ID')
```

Output:

```
   Job_ID   ID    Name         Job  Latest   Prior
0    1234  101    Adam       Sales    Adam    Adam
2    3456  102   Blake  Consultant   Blake  Debbie
4    5678  103   Chris     Analyst   Chris    Eric
1    2345  104  Debbie        Tech  Debbie   Blake
3    4567  105    Eric     Advisor    Eric   Chris
```

Answer (score 0):

Create dictionary first and use [`named-aggregation`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation) with [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
d = {c: (c, 'last') for c in df.columns}
d['Latest'] = ('Name', 'last')
d['Prior'] = ('Name', lambda x: (u:=x.unique())[-2 if len(u) > 1 else -1])
    
out = (df.sort_values('Date', key=pd.to_datetime)
         .groupby('Job_ID')
         .agg(**d)
         .reset_index(drop=True))

print (out)
    ID     Date    Name         Job  Job_ID  Latest   Prior
0  101  03/2022    Adam       Sales    1234    Adam    Adam
1  104  03/2022  Debbie        Tech    2345  Debbie   Blake
2  104  02/2022  Debbie  Consultant    3456  Debbie  Debbie
3  105  03/2022    Eric     Advisor    4567    Eric   Chris
4  103  03/2022   Chris     Analyst    5678   Chris    Eric
```